# Windows Image Acquisition Settings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Here is some code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim F As WIA.ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
    F.SaveFile("C:\Temp\WIA.jpg")
End Sub
```

Through this I can scan a photo with WIA (Windows Image Acquisition)
I want to show acquired image to a picturebox, I also want to delete that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what you've described. Instead of saving the file to disk (requiring later deletion), I just read the scanner's FileData output into a MemoryStream, which can be converted into an Bitmap object, which can be designated as your PictureBox.Image. Like so:

```
Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog
Dim F As WIA.ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)

If F IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim MStream As IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Try
        'Convert the raw scanner output into a byte array
        Dim ImgBytes() As Byte = DirectCast(F.FileData.BinaryData, Byte())
        'Read the image data bytes into a MemoryStream
        MStream = New IO.MemoryStream(ImgBytes)
        'Create a Bitmap from the memory stream data
        Dim Bmp As New Drawing.Bitmap(MStream)
        'Assign the bitmap as the PictureBox Image
        PictureBox1.Image = Bmp
        'Do a victory dance. It worked!
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred while converting scan data to a bitmap: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    If MStream IsNot Nothing Then MStream.Dispose()
End If
```

And there you have it. A bit adapted from my own use but hopefully you won't experience any issues.

To anyone else using this code, you will need to add a reference to the "Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0" COM component to your project.